# retaining combo box selected values..?

Tags: javascript, html

how do i retain combo box value, i mean which ever value i have selected it should retain that value even after refresh or submit..

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing the value through a GET parameter and re loading it through that, or if you're looking for a permanent way you could use cookies to save the value